# iOS Story: Not Enough Room for UIViews In The Sam View Controller

Tags: ios, storyboard

In my app I have a shopping cart, when the user clicks the quantity button, I essentially want the picker (and an accompanying black background), to take up the entire screen space. How do I design this in storyboard? How do I place two full screen UIViews in one ViewController? There isn't enough space for my tableview and picker view to fit in the same view controller. And it doesn't seem like I can drag a UIView directly in storyboard.

[image]

Comment: You can drag on view over top another, and them both be full screen. Set the one you're not working on to be hidden.

Comment: Good idea! Don't think I can have overlapping views in my tableviewcontroller though.

Comment: No, you'll have to use a UIViewController with a table as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to add views inside your main view of the view controller in storyboard. 
Did you try to drag and drop it inside the view?

You can also create a view entirely in code as follows [i like do to it in storyboard as that makes adding constraints a piece of cake]:

1. Subclass UIView to customize your view ... say in class MyView
2. Then from your view controller's ViewDidLoad method you can create and add the view as such

   ```
   self.myView =  [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];

   [self.view addSubview:self.myView];
   // add constraints as needed]
   ```

If you are adding multiple views you will have to be careful about the ordering of the views especially if they are full page. A full page view will hide all other views under it.

The recommended way is that if you want the user action to show a full page view, you should probably create a New ViewController instead of a view.

Hth